# User API for Google App Engine far too restrictive?

Tags: google-app-engine

Looking at the Google App Engine API, it seems that despite all its great features, the User API is extremely limiting.  It seems you can only authenticate people who have a Google account, or use an OpenID account, or via some OAuth kung fu (handshaking with a Facebook account etc).

This appears to be a major stumbling block for anyone who wants a proprietary user base by creating user accounts within the application.  In short, I don't want my users to have to use or create a Google account to access my app.

Has anyone else come across this limitation and has it been a deal breaker for using the GAE? Am I missing something?  It is possible to deploy my own Spring based security etc within the app and use my own User API?  Comments on this issue greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to force users to sign up for your application? They already have enough accounts, and with openid they can at least use one of those.

Comment: Hooray!  I can't wait to be part of yet another "proprietary user base"  I love having to remember new passwords.  so much easier than just using my existing openID account :)

Comment: Work with corporate users much guys? ;-)  I would love to use just OpenIDs, but that will confuse a lot of my user base.  A hybrid authentication model is important when dealing with corporate customers, in the same way as having to support IE as well as FF/Chrome is important as much as we'd like not to have to bother with it.

Answer (score 7):

You're free to completely ignore the Users API and implement your own authentication system, as you would in any other hosting environment. Nothing about App Engine prevents you from doing so.

The Users API is just there as a convenience, in case you'd like to spare yourself the effort of re-implementing everything, and spare your users the inconvenience of filling out another sign up form and remembering another set of credentials.

Comment: That's great, I now have the confirmation I was looking for. Thanks Drew!

Answer (score 2):

You can always implement your own user management system.

In my application I have used spring-security for this purpose. spring security 3.0.1 works perfectly fine with app engine 1.3.5. There may occur some issues integrating other versions of both. I found below links extremely useful :

- http://www.google-app-engine.com/blog/post/Spring-security-fix-for-google-app-engine.aspx.
- http://www.dotnetguru2.org/bmarchesson/index.php?p=1100
- http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/964e7f5e42840d9c